# How to make my own List<T> implementation sortable?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a given List class that uses a LinkedList class to store items and perform various operations. These are not Java's List and LinkedList classes.

I want to be able to sort the items in this list using the collections.sort() method and my own comparators. Naturally sort is not happy with my List class as a parameter.

What do I need to add to my List class to make it sortable? Would List < T extends Comparable < T > > suffice?

Comment: Either make your own list class implement `java.util.List`, or create a method of your list that returns a `List` view of your class. Compare with for instance how `Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(myStringArray))` works; `Arrays.asList` returns a `List` view of the given array.

Comment: Collections.sort will never accept your LinkedList unless you make it implement `java.util.List`.

Comment: *Why* are you not implementing `java.util.List<T>`? A question talking about "my own `List<T>` implementation" makes it sound like you're talking about your own implementation of `java.util.List<T>`. For the sake of readability if nothing else, I would *strongly* urge you to avoid using the same names as classes in `java.util`.

Comment: I am not using the official Lists as this is an assignment for a programming course. So I take it I have to implement my own sorting algorithms in this case. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then change your question, which explicitely ask for being able to sort using Collections.sort(), and thus not using your own sorting algorithm. Make up your mind.

Comment: Well my question is, if I can make a custom list< T > implementation use the collections.sort() ie, can I make my own list class and implement it in such a way for collections.sort() to be happy. The answer seems to be no. @JBNizet

Comment: @user2041427 you can. But then your custom list implementation MUST implement java.util.List<T>, since that's what Collections.sort() takes as argument.